# Saving to a particular column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple doubt..
I have a column named url in a table. And each row in a table is created using active admin. In that there is no provision to give url(It should be like that).
It has got another column with Page_name. and with some calculations(shown below) i do have the required url in a variable. Now i want to update this column url in database with this variable as soon as it is created.
this is what i have done so far.

```
class CustomPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :custom

  def custom
    @custom_page = CustomPage.all
    p "---------------------------------------"
    p @custom_page.last.id
    url = "/custom_page/"+@custom_page.last.page_name.split(" ").join("_")
    CustomPage.where(:id => @custom_page.last.id).update(:url => url)
  end
end
```

and i'm getting some kind of error.
Wrong Number of Arguments (1 for 2).. I hope this is something very small.. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should look like this

```
CustomPage.where(:id => @custom_page.last.id).first.update(:url => url)
```

Since `where` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is in form of a array so you need to fetch the object out of the array

Comment: you're welcome, I've added some more info to the answer, please go through it. Accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `id` to update method like this

```
CustomPage.update(@custom_page.last.id, :url => url)
```

But in this particular case, you can do

```
@custom_page.last.update_attribute(:url, url)
```

Please note that these methods doesn't invoke validations. To do that, call

```
@custom_page.last.update_attributes(:url => url)
```